# VPC Peering if both side VPC CIDR range is same?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking

Is there is any workaround if we have the same vpc cidr (different aws account )at both ends and we want VPC peering? Or any other mechanism which can help me to connect between two same VPC CIDR but in different aws account ??

Answer (score 5):

The peering connection [requires](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/create-vpc-peering-connection.html) **non-overlapping** CIDRs.

> Ensure that your VPCs do not have **overlapping IPv4 CIDR blocks**. If they do, the status of the VPC peering connection immediately goes to failed. This limitation applies even if the VPCs have unique IPv6 CIDR blocks.

A way to deal with such cases is to use **secondary CIDR range**. Such setup is exemplified in the AWS doc:

- [Two VPCs peered to a specific CIDR block in one VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/peering-configurations-partial-access.html#two-vpcs-peered-specific-cidr)

In the example, VPC A has overlapping CIDR range with VPC B and C. To establish peering connection, extra CIDR ranges are used.

Comment: What should I look at in this page? Seems like the HTTP fragment is not valid anymore.

Comment: This answer is misleading. VPCs with overlapping CIDR ranges cannot have a VPC Peering connection. What the linked article describes is using a central VPC as an intermediary.

Answer (score 3):

@marcin referred to this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/peering-configurations-partial-access.html#two-vpcs-peered-specific-cidr

But I would like to provide clarification about using Secondary CIDR Blocks. The second line in that article states:

> In these examples, a central VPC is peered to two or more VPCs that
> have overlapping CIDR blocks.

It provides an example Route Table as so:

```
Route table     Destination     Target
VPC A          VPC A CIDR 1     Local
               VPC A  CIDR 2    Local
               VPC B CIDR       pcx-aaaabbbb
               VPC C CIDR       pcx-aaaacccc
VPC B          VPC B CIDR       Local
               VPC A CIDR 1     pcx-aaaabbbb
VPC C          VPC C CIDR       Local
               VPC A CIDR 2     pcx-aaaacccc
```

This article doesn't suggest that VPC A and VPC B and VPC C can have overlapping CIDRs as long as A creates a secondary CIDR Block that is the one being peered. What the article says is that VPC B and VPC C can have overlapping CIDRs. VPC A **CANNOT** have an Overlapping CIDR with another VPC when you want to create a VPC Peering Connection, even if you are trying to peer with a secondary CIDR. The AWS docs makes that clear:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/vpc-peering-basics.html#vpc-peering-limitations

1. You cannot create a VPC peering connection between VPCs that have
   matching or overlapping IPv4 CIDR blocks.
2. You cannot create a VPC peering connection between VPCs that have
   matching or overlapping IPv6 CIDR blocks.
3. **If you have multiple IPv4 CIDR blocks, you can't create a VPC
   peering connection if any of the CIDR blocks overlap, even if you
   intend to use only the non-overlapping CIDR blocks or only IPv6 CIDR
   blocks**.

In effect, something like this will not work:

```
VPC A CIDR 1 = 192.168.0.0/16
VPC A CIDR 2 = 192.169.0.0/16 
RDS Instance in VPC A id 192.169.10.10

VPC B CIDR = 192.168.0.0/16
Instance in VPC B with 192.168.10.08

Route Table in VPC B that says any traffic destined to 192.169.0.0/16  goes to VPC A through a VPC Peering Connection
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [a good article in AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/connecting-networks-with-overlapping-ip-ranges/) which provides several solutions depending on your needs:

- Renumber IP networks
- Use AWS PrivateLink
- Use multiple IP address ranges in VPCs
- Hide subnets using Private NAT Gateway